# Kvm/ARM, linux: how can the guest code be interrupted?

Tags: linux, arm, kvm

The following code is an excerpt of function [`int kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_run *run)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/arm/kvm/arm.c#L521) (every function that I mention is linked to a hyperlink, but this is not visible from the mobile version!) and it shows what happens when the main vcpu is going to run guest code (context: kvm, arm):

```
    int kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_run *run) {
    //other code 

    preempt_disable();
    kvm_timer_flush_hwstate(vcpu);
    kvm_vgic_flush_hwstate(vcpu);
    local_irq_disable();

    // other code

    kvm_arm_setup_debug(vcpu);

    /**************************************************************
     * Enter the guest
     */
    trace_kvm_entry(*vcpu_pc(vcpu));
    __kvm_guest_enter();
    vcpu->mode = IN_GUEST_MODE;

    ret = kvm_call_hyp(__kvm_vcpu_run, vcpu);

    vcpu->mode = OUTSIDE_GUEST_MODE;
    /*
     * Back from guest
     ************************************************************
    */

    //other code
    local_irq_enable();
    //rest of the function
}
```

I would like to let you focus on function `local_irq_disable()`: while we are in hypervisor mode (so executing the guest), we don't want to take HOST interrupts, so `local_irq_disable()` function lets all the HOST interrupts PENDING while we execute the guest.

What I need to figure out is that how the GuestOS can come back to HostOS when an interrupt happens.
I did track that GuestOS comes back to HostOS upon a [`__kvm_vcpu_return`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/arch/arm64/kvm/hyp.S#L962). `__kvm_vcpu_return` is in turn called by [`el1_trap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/arch/arm64/kvm/hyp.S#L1199) or by [`el1_irq`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/arch/arm64/kvm/hyp.S#L1265). What I can't figure out is how such interrupts are taken into account if we called `local_irq_disable()` function before entering in the guest (namely, before invoking `__kvm_guest_enter()`). Theoretically, EL1 interrupts shall be disabled, not?